# Sencha ExtJS PDF Download

Tags: python, django, pdf, extjs, download

I have a rather complex frontend in `Sencha ExtJS` with a `Python/Django` Backend.

I need to download `PDFs` via the `Django` Backend, which needs authentication. I tried an iFrame and window.open but I can not pass the `auth` token with this approach.

How can I accomplish the pdf download from the backend with authentication?

Thanks in advance,

Reto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use Ext.Ajax request. Something like this:

```
const authToken = 'SomeAuthToken';
const fileName = 'SomeFile.pdf';
const fileType = 'application/pdf';

Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: './' + fileName,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': authToken
    },
    binary: true,
    success: function (response, opts) {
        var windowUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var url = windowUrl.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.responseBytes], {type: fileType}));
        var anchor = document.createElement('a');
        anchor.href = url;
        anchor.download = fileName;
        anchor.click();
    },

    failure: function (response, opts) {
        console.log('server-side failure with status code ' + response.status);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks indeed for your help. Your solution solved my problem!